# Applying the Shapiro Wilk test to a large number of numeric variables to test for normality

Tags: r, normality-assumption

I am working with data from a cellular network and I have 5000+ variables (cells in the network) and for each of these variables I have measurements of noise levels. Each variable has 175 samples and the data is continuous in nature but has been sampled every 15 mins. This is my dataset, 175 x 5000+ values all measuring the same metric, noise levels in dBm.

Since this data is timeseries data, I was looking at the Hurst exponent to explain the long term memory for each of the variables (5000+). I then plotted the distribution of the H values and the graph in green is the outcome. As you can see below the distribution of H values is approximately normal.

It has been suggested to me in conversation that since the Hurst exponent is approximately normally distributed then the underlying data is also normally distributed. But I know from working with the data that for each variable the distribution is right skewed rather than normally distributed. I would like to either prove or disprove this statement and I am looking for a procedure to test this.

I came across [this](http://msme.us/2011-1-2.pdf) paper where the authors had randomly generated a couple of hundred time series and the Hurst distribution of these couple of Hundred time series were also normally distributed. So I guess I wanted to disprove the belief that the underlying data was also normal.

I hope what I am trying to do is a bit clearer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you want to know the true distribution of each of the 5000+ variables? Do you think they all come from the same distribution or that the could all be distributed differently?

Comment: After reading this over several times, I still haven't figured out what you're trying to ask.  Could you clarify what you mean by "original data this was derived from," "the data" (which are "actually right skewed"), the "this" you wish to provide evidence for, and "each variable in the dataset" (which dataset and which variables)? Note that your final question about "the hypothesis that the dataset is normally distributed" has an immediate, simple, and definitive answer: you don't have Normally distributed data.  What, then, are you asking??

Comment: @whuber, I have updated the question to provide more clarity. Let me know if it's a bit clearer now.

Comment: Thank you; that works very well.  I am baffled--and perhaps you are too--at the assertion that (approximate) normality of Hurst exponents implies normality of the underlying data. You have just posted a clear counterexample. It scarcely needs formal testing.

Comment: @whuber, but I do need to test it, that's the problem. I'm not a statistician so I'm not entirely confident in how to approach this. Can I take the mean of all the mean values of each variable and the median of all the median values for each variable and say that since the median is greater than the mean then the data is not normal and is right skewed?

Comment: I'm trying to get clear about the "it" that you think you need to test.  I see three possibilities:  (a) the Hurst exponent is approximately normally distributed; (b) the underlying data are normally distributed; (c) the conditional that if the Hurst exponent is approximately normally distributed then the underlying data is also normally distributed.  (b) is clearly false.  If you think you need to test (a) across all 5000+ variables, you could use Shapiro-Wilk with a [FWER](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate) correction.

Comment: If you think you need to test (c), then you just need one solid counterexample.  For that, you might use Shapiro-Wilk across all 5000+ variables, but — instead of correcting the FWER — select the case with the *largest* p-value.  You're not testing a hypothesis here; you just want to identify the "most normal" variable, to use as your counterexample.  (For SW, the *null* is a normal distribution, so higher p-value means "closer" to a normal distribution.)

Comment: @Great38 yes naturally some of them could be normally distributed but for the most part they should be right skewed. If there was a problem with one of the variables i.e. external noise interference we would see more samples around -95dBm but for the most part for all cells normal operating range in -105dBm up to -102dBm. Of course there will be outliers, hence right skewed. It is impossible to have measurements >-110dBm, the equipment can't measure any lower than this value. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: I'd focus on measuring non-normality rather than testing it if that is your concern. Whenever you know there is right-skewness the tests won't change your mind. Concretely, calculate skewness, kurtosis and their L-moments equivalents.

Comment: What does it mean that "the underlying data is also normally distributed"? This relates to the distribution of the noise levels at all 175 different time-points of a single 'variable', or does it relate to the distribution of the noise at a single time-point (or averaged value) of all 5000 variables? What connecting mechanism do you expect between the Hurst coefficient and the distribution of the data. It is very simple to construct counter examples. but maybe the "theorem" from the conversation is depending on certain additional assumptions and conditions.